# Calling MainApplication methods from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-service

I have an Android Application with an Activity, a service and a Broadcast receiver. From the service I call a Broadcast Intent which works. The Broadcast Receiver receives the intent correctly.

But how can I access methods of the class `MainApplication` from my Class `MyBroadcastReceiver` ?

`((MainApplication)getApplication()).myMethod();` gives the error-message "cannot resolve method"

```
//Call from the service-class
private void sendBroadcast() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Sending Broadcast Intent");
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("com.package.name.MyBroadcastReceiver");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}


//receiver class
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Doesn't work - "cannot resolve method"
        ((MainApplication)getApplication()).myMethod();
        //Doesn't work either
        ((MainApplication)context.getApplication()).myMethod();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Intent Detected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}



//Main Application Class
public class MainApplication extends Application{

    public void myMethod(){

    }

}
```

Best regards

Comment: See comment in code.. "cannot resolve method"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast the context to an Activity:

```
//receiver class
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Activity activity = (Activity) context;
        ((MainApplication)activity.getApplication()).myMethod();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Intent Detected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Very quick and easy solution.

Answer (score 1):

The above usually happens if you haven't declared you `MainApplication` class in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Find the `application` tag in your AndroidManifest.xml file, and ensure it's name attribute points to your `MainApplication` - something like below.

```
<application
        android:name="com.you.package.MainApplication"
```

Comment: Thank you. On another occasion this was the right answer. But this time i have put the MainApplication in the AndroidManifest.xml file. The same call `((MainApplication)getApplication()).myMethod();` works, if I use it from another class, but unfortunately not when I try to call it from the `MyBroadcastReceiver`-class.

Answer (score 0):

Create the BroadcastReceiver dynamically:

In your BroadcastReceiver class define class member:

```
YourMainActivity yourMain = null;
```

and method:

```
setMainActivityHandler(YourMainActivity main){
yourMain = main;
}
```

from your MainActivity do:

```
private YourBroadcastReceiverClassName yourBR = null;
yourBR = new YourBroadcastReceiverClassName();
    yourBR.setMainActivityHandler(this);    
    IntentFilter callInterceptorIntentFilter = new           IntentFilter("android.intent.action.ANY_ACTION");
    registerReceiver(yourBR,  callInterceptorIntentFilter);
```

when yourBR.onReceive is fired you can call:

```
yourMain.methodOfMainActivity();
```